# Использование List С#

Tags: c#, list, vector

Коллеги, вопрос на засыпку: В `с++` можно определить изначально *размер прямоугольного вектора*, ну например:

```
vector<vector<int>>primer(4,vector<int>(3))
```

то есть вектор будет 4 на 3.

А в `С#` такое возможно?
Например:
Конструкция вида:

```
List<List<int>> tt=new List<List<int>>(5,List<int>(3));
```

не определена.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

пользуемся мощью методов расширения:

```
static class ListExtension{
    public static List<T> Fill<T>(this List<T> list, T value){
        for(var i=0; i<list.Capacity;i++){
            list.Add(value);
        }
        return list;
    }
}

void Main()
{
    var list = new List<List<int>>(4).Fill(new List<int>(4)/*.Fill(0)*/);
    list.Dump();

    // эквивалентно:
    var list1 = new List<List<int>>{
        new List<int>{0,0,0,0},
        new List<int>{0,0,0,0},
        new List<int>{0,0,0,0},
        new List<int>{0,0,0,0}
    };
}
```

Comment: Хм, "верхний" список заполнится одним и тем объектом же... И то что "эквивалентно" - на самом деле не эквивалентно, там 4 раза список создается, а в первом варианте один раз всего...

Answer (score 5):

"Прямоугольный вектор":

```
int[,] tt = new int[4, 3];
```

Comment: +1, только `int[,] tt` наверное?

Comment: Это не C++, int[,] tt == null.

Comment: Имелось в виду именно List, а не встроенный тип массива. Почему - для использования в многомерных циклах (не очень хочется писать что-то типа for(int i=0; i<число; i++).... Проще писать for(int i=0; i<list.cout; l++) итд :)

Comment: >> не очень хочется писать что-то типа for(int i=0; i<число; i++).... Проще писать for(int i=0; i<list.cout; l++) итд

Что мешает писать for(int i=0; i<myArray.Length; i++) ?

Comment: В принципе-да. Можно же так: 
int [][] mass=new int [3][];
mass[0] = new int[4] { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
....mass[0].Length
Гранд мерси. В с++ такого нельзя было..)

И все же можно ли задать границы в List (уже ради спортивного интереса).

Answer (score 0):

Можно написать вспомогательный метод для создания `List<T>` и его заполнения:

```
public static List<T> CreateList<T>(int capacity, Func<T> valueGenerator)
{
    var list = new List<T>(capacity);
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; ++i)
        list.Add(valueGenerator());
    return list;
}
```

Теперь мы можем создавать многомерные "векторы":

```
List<List<int>> list = CreateList(4, () => new List<int>(4));
```